# requesting a server by checking/unchecking checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, razor

I'm trying to code a web page that contains two checkboxes and to send a request to my web server for each check/uncheck. I have to check at server side which checkboxes are checked and which are not to make some specific operations.

Form (snippet of code) :

```
<form method="get" action="@Url.Action("Index")" data-monitoring-ajax="true" data-monitoring-target="#ListeAlertes">
    <input type="checkbox" name="affiche" value="fixees" id="fixees" style="margin-left:40px;margin-right:3px;" checked /> Alertes fixées
    <input type="checkbox" name="affiche" value="nonFixees" id="nonFixees" style="margin-left:10px;margin-right:3px;" checked /> Alertes non-fixées
</form>
```

monitoring.js

```
$(function () {

    var ajaxFormSubmit = function () {
        var $form = $(this);

        var options = {
            url: $form.attr("action"),
            type: $form.attr("method"),
            data: $form.serialize()
        };

        $.ajax(options).done(function (data) {
            var $target = $($form.attr("data-monitoring-target"));
            $target.replaceWith(data);
        });
        return false;
    }

    $("form[data-monitoring-ajax='true']").submit(ajaxFormSubmit);

});
```

**Note :** I've included monitoring.js into the web page.

Any brilliant idea, please ?

Comment: You need to give your checkboxes different names, or use array-style names.

Comment: @Barmar: if I change their names, how can I catch their values ?

Comment: You use different variables in the server code to get each checkbox value. If you don't give them different names, how would you read both values?

Comment: It looks like the two checkboxes are for opposite options. Why are you using two boxes? Either use a single checkbox or radio buttons.

Comment: @user3264174  So when the user clicks a checkbox you want it sent to the server right away or do you want them to make selections and then submit it via ajax?

Comment: @Barmar, I thought receving them in a table. If I give them different names how do I can check if they are unchecked, will receive a void value ?

Comment: What language are you using on the server?

Comment: @Justin, I just need to make a request for each check/uncheck there is no submits.

Comment: @Barmar, C# / ASP.NET MVC 4 / Razor

Comment: Unchecked boxes are never sent to the server, it doesn't matter if you give them the same or different names. In PHP, if you want to receive multiple inputs with the same name, you have to name them `affiche[]` and it puts the values into an array. I don't know how ASP.NET does it, I assumed it was similar. If you give them different names, just check whether you received an input with each name.

Comment: @Barmar, ok no problem, do you think that the problem comes from the Ajax Call ?

Comment: What problem are you having? Your question just asked how to send the checkboxes to the server, which Tushar Gupta answered below.

Comment: @Barmar, I've asked about how to send checkboxes to the server for each check/uncheck.

Comment: You're not explaining the problem well, because it looks to me like he answered that. Do you want to send just one checkbox instead of sending both of them, is that the problem?

Comment: @Barmar, look at the response of Justin, it's a bit what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the options seem to represent the same item just in a different state, you really only need one checkbox.

### The Html

```
<input type="checkbox" id="enableAlerts" style="margin-left:40px;margin-right:3px;" /> Alertes fixées
```

---

### The javascript (jQuery)

With this, you can subscribe to the `change` event to know when to send the request to the server.

```
$("#enableAlerts").change(function(){
    $.post("/Controller/UpdateAlerts",
           { enableAlerts: this.checked },
            function(data){ console.log("Successfully saved user options!"); });
});
```

In the above script we listen for the change event to fire and when it does, we post our data to the server so it can process it.  If the server returns a 200 status code, it will write to the console that it was successful.  Since only one checkbox is being sent, there isn't any reason to wrap the checkbox in a form and serialize the form to send to the server.

---

### The Server code

Now all you need is a controller/action to call to update the option on the server.

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpStatusCodeResult UpdateAlerts(bool enableAlerts)
{
    //Save to database

    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

The above code allows the javascript code to post the data to the server.  In this case I allowed the value to be nullable and default to false if so.  After that, do what you need to and return a response code so the client-side code can inform the user of the status of their request.

---

## In response to comment by user

In this case wrapping it in a form would be correct.  The majority of the steps are similar with minor modifications.

### Html

```
<form method="post" id="filterOptions">
    <input type="checkbox" name="Checkbox1" value="true" /> 
    <input type="checkbox" name="Checkbox2" value="true" /> 
</form>
```

---

### Javascript

```
$("#filterOptions input[type='checkbox']").change(function () {
        var form = $("#filterOptions").serialize();
        $.post("/Controller/AjaxFilteredList", 
               form,
               function (data) { console.log("Retrieved data successfully!") });
});
```

---

### The Model

```
public class MyModel
{
    public bool Checkbox1 { get; set; }
    public bool Checkbox2 { get; set; }
}
```

The model's property names must match the name of the property, case-insensitive.  This is made easier if you make this a `ViewModel` and pass it into the repective `View` and use `Html.CheckboxFor(m => m.Checkbox1)` to render the checkbox.

---

### The controller action

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AjaxFilteredList(MyModel model)
{
    //check you viewmodel's variables to get your list

    return PartialView("_FilteredList", filteredList);
}
```

The above assumes you have a partial view named "_FilteredList" and a variable named "filteredList" in-scope with the results you want to render.

Comment: In fact, Checking these checkboxes the end-user will send a request asking the server to send him back a list of items refering to the value of the selected checkbox, and in case of the two checkboxes are checked or unchecked the server will return the full list. For instance, if the first checkbox is checked, the server will send back a list which contains items where (fixee==true) and if both of them are checked it'll be all items. Sorry if my post wasn't clear.

Comment: @user3264174 I edited my post and added a simple solution to what I think you want.  You can always improve on top of the example.  When creating the search from, you should use a `ViewModel` to create the filter form to ensure the server can bind the form variable to the model on posting to the server.  You can change the operation from a `POST` to a `GET` also considering the nature of the request.

Answer (score 0):

Use [.change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/)

```
$("form[data-monitoring-ajax='true'] input[type='checkbox']").change(function(){
     //make your Ajax Call here and send name of the checkbox or id of the checkobox
});
```

---

[Attribute Equals Selector [name="value"]](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

Comment: Why use `.find` instead of combining the selectors?

Comment: @TusharGupta, this wouldn't work, do you think that the problem comes from the ajax call, please ?

Comment: @user3264174 oh sorry i misunderstood the Question now i got it.You have to change the name of the checkbox no other option .

Comment: @TusharGupta, then how to catch their change of check ?

Comment: @user3264174 can u please explain what u mean by change of check ? what are you doing u with the change and where is that code.

Comment: @user3264174 you can make use radio button .

Comment: @TusharGupta, I need to allow the possibility of two checks